# I'm trying to remember a book, in which learning a new profession = learning a new language

Tags: story-identification, languages

I remember an interesting book, in which the state of science was quite advanced, and, the process of learning a particular advanced profession was less about learning the related skills, and more about learning how to speak the language.

Can you help me identify this book (or maybe it was a series)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That reminds me of Charles Sheffield's novella *"At the Eschaton"* which became *"Tomorrow and Tomorrow"*, 1997

> "Language must have changed completely," I said. "I cannot understand
>   them at all." "Understand them? The doctors?" He looked surprised. "Of
>   course not. Neither can I. Naturally they are speaking Medicine. " I
>   raised my eyebrows. The look  must have survived with its meaning
>   intact, for he went on. "I speak Music and History..."

Answer (score 5):

You might be thinking of "The Languages of Pao", by Jack Vance.

[Obligatory Wikipedia cite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Languages_of_Pao)

Comment: That's not quite it - in the book I'm looking for, languages evolved as a side effect of the level of specialization required before being able to participate in work in a particular field.