# Story Identification: Man freezes himself and his wife in the hopes of curing her terminal illness

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, suspended-animation

I read this story when I was very young and can't remember the name but it made an impression. A young man finds out that his wife has a terminal illness, so convinces her to be put into some kind of suspended animation. He plans to do the same to himself but first tries to figure out a way to become an important enough person so that there is a higher likelihood of him and his wife being saved in the event of some future tragedy. He's a musician or composer but decides to spend the next few years interviewing and gathering information about important composers, artists, etc of his day--he hopes that by gathering the more subjective, human bits of information he can become valuable to future historians as a source of knowledge that isn't easily found anywhere else.

He ends up waking at certain intervals and describing the world he finds in a similar way. One thing that stood out was that in the far, far, future human's had specialized professionally to such a degree that each group spoke their own language: doctors spoke a language heavily influenced by medical ideas, physicists spoke one influenced by physics etc.

I may have gotten certain details of the story wrong, but to my 8 or 9 year old self, this story was awesome and I'd love any information anyone can provide. Thanks!

Comment: The languages piece seems similar to this question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11837/1234

Comment: well looks like the history of Mr. Frezee but not sure, maybe mr freeze its based in some book http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Freeze

Comment: @Xantec You should update that question with the answer provided by Donald Mclean or he should. It sounds like the correct answer.

Answer (score 17):

The story is [Tomorrow and Tomorrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomorrow_and_Tomorrow_%28novel%29) by Charles Sheffield. We read this in our book group and it is an incredible story.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the responses--"Tomorrow and Tomorrow" is it! Really happy to finally have this one settled--thanks Donald.

Comment: @Tomas If this is the correct answer please consider accepting it as such (click the little check mark to the left).