# Man undergoes cryonic suspension, through multiple millennia. Has a redhead girl friend and they reunite in each age

Tags: story-identification

I read this novel in the 90s. The main character goes into cryonic suspension several times.
In one era the planet is dying. Humans are struggling to survive. There are very few humans, life is grim and they live underground. He freezes again, and millennia later humans live in space stations above earth. He is sort of a concubine for a female leader. They also have genetically modified gorillas as servants.
 At each of the times he always somehow reunites with his girlfriend who has also frozen and reawakened. She's a redhead.

It'd be amazing if someone can ID this novel.

Comment: Sounds familiar. Reminds me of [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17558/story-identification-man-freezes-himself-and-his-wife-in-the-hopes-of-curing-he), but I don't remember what color her hair was. Is it the same story?

Comment: Here's the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomorrow_and_Tomorrow_%28novel%29) for Sheffield's *Tomorrow and Tomorrow*, just in case that's the one you're looking for.

Comment: John C. Wright recently wrote a book with a similar plot device (cryonic suspension through millenias). It's _The Hermetic Millenia_, the sequel to _Count to a Trillion_. They were published in 2011 and 2012, so they can't be the books you're looking for, but they're still good reads, if that kind of story interests you!

Comment: I'm afraid it's not "Tomorrow and Tomorrow". But it sounds like a great read.

Comment: It's not Orson Scott Card's Worthing Safa either, but similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I found the book. All help greatly appreciated.

Its "The World at the End of Time" by Frederik Pohl. 1990
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_at_the_End_of_Time

The key was when I remembered the plot also involving terraforming and a sleepership.

Answer (score 2):

I think its " A_World_Out_of_Time"  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_World_Out_of_Time

In the end of the story its told she "Mirelly-Lyra" has red hair again .

The story can be found here : http://www.e-reading.mobi/chapter.php/75688/9/Niven_-_A_World_Out_of_Time.html

Comment: That sounds really promising, and you've even provided the book. I'll read it now!